# jquery .click function onto a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, while-loop

Good afternoon,

So I have this simple loop and basically I'd like to create an event for anytime the user clicks on any line created by the loop.

This is my very simple php while loop:

```
<?php
$x = 1; 
while($x <= 5) {
    ?>
    <div id="number"><?php echo "$x <br>";?></div><?php
    $x++;
}
?>
```

and this is my jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#number").click(function(){
        alert("click");
    });
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately, the alert only activates itself when I click on the first number.
Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Edit:I feel very dumb, I should've used class instead, thanks Tushar

Comment: **ID should be Unique**, use class instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel extremely stupid

Comment: @Cancerbro, why is it good afternoon? It's early mornin' over here for me. ;). Anyways yeah, Tushar is right, put everything with the same class. They can still have a separate ID but in this case you would want to use a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery selector will find only the first row, because they all get the same id. use a class selector and an id scheme you can use. For example:

```
<?php
for ( $x =0 ; $x < 5 ; $x++ ) {
    ?>
    <div id="number<?php echo $x ?>" class="myclass"><?php echo "$x <br>" ; ?></div><?
}
?>
```

Now you can select like this:

```
$("div[id^=number]").click (function () { alert ("click") ; }) ;
```

or

```
$("div.myclass").click (function () { alert ("click") ; }) ;
```

the last one should be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
$x = 1; 
while($x <= 5) {
    ?>
    <div class="number"><?php echo "$x <br>";?></div><?php
    $x++;
}
?>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".number").click(function(){
        alert("click");
    });
});


Id should be unique.So added class.
```